# Fire event when datatables sorting is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

I'm initialing my datatable just fine and everything functions except that some of my columns take a long time (3-5 seconds) to sort. I only have around 350 rows, but about 25 columns (not all visible at once).

I'm doing something like this to make a column visible and then sort.

```
$('#main_index').on('click', 'thead th', function() { 

                        var idx = table.column(this).index();
                        selected_data = table.column(idx).dataSrc();

    if (selected_data == 'diabetes_full') {
                                table.order([4, 'desc']);

                                table.columns('.col_rank').visible(false);
                                table.column(3).visible(true);
                                 table.draw();
                                $(".rank").hide();
                                $("#diabetes_full_rank").show();

                            } else if (selected_data == 'pop_with_diabetes') {
                                table.order([6, 'desc']);
                                table.columns('.col_rank').visible(false);
                                table.column(5).visible(true);
                                 table.draw();
                                $(".rank").hide();
                                $("#pop_with_diabetes_rank").show();
                            }
});
```

Like I said, this works but sometimes is a little slow. I'm not sure I can find a way to speed things up (suggestions welcome), but I'd like to be able to show a loading message when the sorting is still taking place and hide it when the sorting is complete.

I've tried all sorts of things working off of `table.draw()` including:

```
$.when(table.draw()).then(//function to hide loading message);
```

I've tried using `drawCallback` and several others. What I'm noticing is that the table draw is basically instantaneous, but the actual completion of the sorting comes after this. However, I don't know how to bind an event to the sort being complete or if datatables has a way to handle this. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you already have default sorting working you are likely conflicting with it by calling `draw()` yourself. Is it normal speed when you comment out the above?

Comment: Can you use `processing: true`?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com This doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @charlietfl I think this might be the problem. Are you saying I don't need to use `draw()` where I have it in my code?

Comment: Not sure which draw will happen first to be honest. Probably the internal one since event handlers would have been added before yours. Curious though what difference is when you sort without your code. Also think events api would be better to dig into. If an event occurs before sort you might be able to just modify options then and may not need to call draw yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to listen to the order event.
order event - fired when the data contained in the table is ordered.
You can find more info here https://datatables.net/reference/event/.
You can read more about how to listen to the datatable events here: https://datatables.net/manual/events

EDIT

I re-read your question and realized that I may be wrong about the specific event you will need to use. If you are saying you want to trigger an action once a column is reordered (which is actually what I think you want) you will want to look at column-reorder (Columns have been reordered by the end user or API). Info is on the same link.

Comment: The order event seems to fire when the order is initiated and not when completed (at least this is how it's working for my table).